# Chartjs polar area curved labels

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js

I'm trying to create curved labels for a Polar Area graph using Chart.js, like this:

[image]

I have found [this issue](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/issues/344) where they discuss it, but it doesn't seem to have an answer yet.

So far, I'm only being able to display the labels at the side of the graph, but not in a curved way:

```js
Chart.register( ChartDataLabels );


const config = {
    "type": "polarArea",
    "data": {
        "labels": [
            "aaaaaaaa",
            "bbbbbbbb",
            "cccccccc",
            "dddddddd",
            "eeeeeeee",
            "ffffffff",
            "gggggggg",
            "hhhhhhhh"
        ],
        "datasets": [
            {
                "data": [
                    80,
                    40,
                    54,
                    62,
                    71,
                    45,
                    50,
                    85
                ],
                "backgroundColor": [
                    "#674ea7",
                    "#db4b4b",
                    "#2f2f6e",
                    "#3c1414",
                    "#fc3631",
                    "#556b2f",
                    "#820000",
                    "#76a5af"
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    "options": {
        "responsive": true,
        "scales": {
            "r": {
                "angleLines": {
                    "display": true
                },
                "ticks": {
                    "display": false
                },
                "pointLabels": {
                  "display": true,
                  "centerPointLabels": true,
                  "font": {
                    "size": 14
                  }
                }
            }
        },
        "scale": {
            "min": 0,
            "max": 100,
            "ticks": {
                "display": false,
                "beginAtZero": true
            }
        },
        "plugins": {
            "legend": {
                "position": 'top',
            },
            "datalabels": {
                "formatter": (value, context) => value + '%',
                "color": "#ffffff"
            }
        }
    }
}

const ctx = document.getElementById( 'graph' ).getContext( '2d' );

const chart = new Chart( ctx, config );
```

[image]

Does anyone know how to do it?

Answer (score 2):

[Fraser](https://stackoverflow.com/users/74861/fraser) suggested to use [chartjs-plugin-labels](https://github.com/emn178/chartjs-plugin-labels). The problem is, that `chartjs-plugin-labels` is no longer maintained and doesn't support Chart.js v3.

Therefore, you should use [chart.js-plugin-labels-dv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/chart.js-plugin-labels-dv). This plugin was forked from `chartjs-plugin-labels` and adapted for Chart.js v3.

```
plugins: {
  labels: {
    arc: true,
    fontColor: '#000',
    position: 'outside',
    fontSize: 14,
    render: (args) => args.dataset.helper ? args.label : '',
    fontColor: (args) => legendLabelColors[args.index] 
  }
}
```

> Note that `labels.render` makes sure, that the data labels are drawn for the outer   (helper) dataset only.

Please take a look at your amended and runnable code and see how it works.

```js
Chart.register( ChartDataLabels );

const legendLabelColors = ["rgb(255, 99, 132)", "rgb(255, 159, 64)", "rgb(255, 205, 86)", "rgb(75, 192, 192)", "rgb(54, 162, 235)", "rgb(153, 102, 255)", "rgb(201, 203, 207)", "rgb(54, 162, 88)"];

const config = {
    type: "polarArea",
    data: {
        labels: ["aaaaaaaa", "bbbbbbbb", "cccccccc", "dddddddd", "eeeeeeee", "ffffffff", "gggggggg", "hhhhhhhh"],
        datasets: [
            {
                data: [80, 40, 54, 62, 71, 45, 50, 85],
                backgroundColor: ["rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.5)", "rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.5)", "rgba(255, 205, 86, 0.5)", "rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.5)", "rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.5)", "rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.5)", "rgba(201, 203, 207, 0.5)", "rgba(54, 162, 88, 0.5)"],
                datalabels: {
                   formatter: (value, context) => value + '%',
                   color: "#ffffff"
                },
            },
            {
                helper: true,
                data: [100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100],
                backgroundColor: ["rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)", "rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)", "rgba(255, 205, 86, 0.2)", "rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)", "rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)", "rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)", "rgba(201, 203, 207, 0.2)", "rgba(54, 162, 88, 0.2)"],
                datalabels: {
                   display: false
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    options: {
        layout: {
          padding: 20
        },
        scales: {
            r: {
                angleLines: {
                    display: true
                },
                ticks: {
                    display: false
                },
                pointLabels: {
                  display: false
                }
            }
        },
        scale: {
            min: 0,
            max: 100
        },
        plugins: {
            labels: {
              arc: true,
              fontColor: '#000',
              position: 'outside',
              fontSize: 14,
              render: (args) => args.dataset.helper ? args.label : '',
              fontColor: (args) => legendLabelColors[args.index] 
            }
        }
    }
}

const chart = new Chart( 'graph', config );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.9.1/chart.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chartjs-plugin-datalabels@2"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/chart.js-plugin-labels-dv/dist/chartjs-plugin-labels.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="graph"></canvas>
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing this. Looks like the most promising suggestion so far.
However, when I try it out, chartjs doesnt seem to accept a "label" plugin for type=polarArea charts.

Is this something that you've ran into?
I've seen your Angular sandbox project, demonstrating a "pie" chart and couldn't really find the answer there.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [chartjs-plugin-labels](https://github.com/emn178/chartjs-plugin-labels) to achieve this

You can see a [working example here](https://emn178.github.io/chartjs-plugin-labels/samples/demo/)

The key is to set `arc` to `true` and `position` to `outside` in the plugin options. e.g.

```
{
  labels: {
    render: 'label',
    arc: true,
    fontColor: '#000',
    position: 'outside'
  }
}
```

Comment: I could swear I tried this plugin, but it didn't work! Thank you, man; I'm going to test it ;)