# Can we Achieve a label in circular Format inside the graph

Tags: reactjs, chart.js, nest

Is it possible to create the label like this using Chart.js and how. If any library supports tell me. This is in react

I need the label as it is in React using chartjs,

I am trying using this code , If anybody knows please let me know, I am struggling to do this one

This is the code, try to give answers if u found anything

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import Chart from "chart.js/auto";
import ChartDataLabels from "chartjs-plugin-datalabels";
import { MuiTooltip } from "../../components";

const Graph = () => {
  const chartRef = useRef(null);
  const chartInstance = useRef(null);
  let tooltip = false;

  useEffect(() => {
    const renderChart = () => {
      const ctx = chartRef.current.getContext("2d");

      if (chartInstance.current !== null) {
        chartInstance.current.destroy(); // Destroy previous chart instance
      }

      chartInstance.current = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: "doughnut",
        data: {
          labels: [
            "SHAPES STRATEGY",
            "BUILDS CULTURE BUILDS",
            "SCALES LEADERSHIP",
            "DRIVES EXECUTION",
          ],
          datasets: [
            {
              data: [25, 25, 25, 25],
              backgroundColor: ["rgb(55, 99, 132)"],
              borderColor: ["white", "white", "white", "white"],
              borderWidth: 2,
            },
          ],
        },
        options: {
          cutout: "65%",
          radius: "100%",
          spacing: 3,
          rotation: -0.5 * Math.PI,
          plugins: {
            legend: { display: false },
            datalabels: {
              color: '#FFFFFF',
              formatter: (value, ctx) => {
                return ctx.chart.data.labels[ctx.dataIndex];
              },
              generateLabels: (context) => {
                const labels = context.chart.data.labels;
                const points = context.chart.data.datasets[0].data;
                const total = points.reduce((acc, point) => acc + point, 0);
                const radius = context.chart.outerRadius * 0.7; // Adjust radius as needed
                const rotation = -0.5 * Math.PI;

                return labels.map((label, index) => {
                  const angle = rotation + (Math.PI * 2 * points.slice(0, index).reduce((acc, point) => acc + point, 0)) / total;
                  return {
                    text: label,
                    color: 'white',
                    textAlign: 'center',
                    font: { size: 12 },
                    offset: {
                      x: radius * Math.cos(angle),
                      y: radius * Math.sin(angle),
                    },
                  };
                });
              },
            },
          },
        },
        plugins: [ChartDataLabels],
      });
    };

    renderChart();

    return () => {
      if (chartInstance.current !== null) {
        chartInstance.current.destroy(); // Clean up the chart on component unmount
      }
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <div style={{ marginLeft: "6rem", width: 700, height: 700, marginTop: "5rem" }}>
      <MuiTooltip title={tooltip} position="bottom">
        <canvas ref={chartRef}></canvas>
      </MuiTooltip>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Graph;
```

Comment: This answer may help you finding a solution for your case: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73982317/2358409. You may have to play with the value of `plugins.labels.position`.